# Node.js: SOAP request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to perform a request from an existing Node.js server. The request has been given to me using an XML format, but I'm clueless about how to use that... Please have a look at it and give me some directions about how these are usually handled?

Thanks in advance...

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:api="http://api.__SOME_DOMAIN__.com">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <api:userToken>
         <password>pwd</password>
         <username>usr</username>
      </api:userToken>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <api:SearchModels>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <searchText>__KEYWORD__</searchText>
      </api:SearchModels>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for this same question, and it looks like the [node-soap-ly](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-soap-ly) is rather easy to use. I don't see your wsdl location posted here, but you should be able to copy the code the `soap.createClient` from that link and then your args would be:

```
args = {
  searchText: '__KEYWORD__';
}
```

Er, that package doesn't tell how to set the headers though, so you'll have to dig further to find that.